# Jpa findAll() results in error when consulting a table that includes a java.sql.Date column

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Hello I am learning Java in college and Spring-Boot by my own. This is my first solo project. I want to make a Restful API for the example nation-db from this [MariaDB Tutorial.](https://www.mariadbtutorial.com/getting-started/mariadb-sample-database/)
Well there is a countries table which has a "national_day" date type column that I suspect is causing the problem. I made a @Repository class which extends JpaRepository so I can use findAll() and other methods. After that I did some console prints in order to check if I was able to get the data and I got the right answer on every consult I did except when I try the findAll() method. I did another test adding the @Transient annotation above the national_day column and findAll() runs but with the national_day column getting nulls.
These are my java classes:
Countries entity

```
package me.givo.nationdbapiproject.model;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "countries")
public class Countries {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "country_id", length = 11, nullable = false)
    private Integer country_id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 50, nullable = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "area", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal area;

    // @Transient
    @Column(name = "national_day", nullable = true)
    private java.sql.Date national_day;

    @Column(name = "country_code2", length = 2, nullable = false)
    private String country_code2;

    @Column(name = "country_code3", length = 3, nullable = false)
    private String country_code3;

    public Integer getCountry_id() {
        return country_id;
    }

    public void setCountry_id(Integer country_id) {
        this.country_id = country_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(BigDecimal area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    public java.sql.Date getNational_day() {
        return national_day;
    }

    public void setNational_day(java.sql.Date national_day) {
        this.national_day = national_day;
    }

    public String getCountry_code2() {
        return country_code2;
    }

    public void setCountry_code2(String country_code2) {
        this.country_code2 = country_code2;
    }

    public String getCountry_code3() {
        return country_code3;
    }

    public void setCountry_code3(String country_code3) {
        this.country_code3 = country_code3;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Countries [area=" + area + ", country_code2=" + country_code2 + ", country_code3=" + country_code3
                + ", country_id=" + country_id + ", name=" + name + ", national_day=" + national_day + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((area == null) ? 0 : area.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((country_code2 == null) ? 0 : country_code2.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((country_code3 == null) ? 0 : country_code3.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((country_id == null) ? 0 : country_id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((national_day == null) ? 0 : national_day.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Countries other = (Countries) obj;
        if (area == null) {
            if (other.area != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!area.equals(other.area))
            return false;
        if (country_code2 == null) {
            if (other.country_code2 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!country_code2.equals(other.country_code2))
            return false;
        if (country_code3 == null) {
            if (other.country_code3 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!country_code3.equals(other.country_code3))
            return false;
        if (country_id == null) {
            if (other.country_id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!country_id.equals(other.country_id))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (national_day == null) {
            if (other.national_day != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!national_day.equals(other.national_day))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Countries repository

```
package me.givo.nationdbapiproject.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import me.givo.nationdbapiproject.model.Countries;

@Repository
public interface ICountriesJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Countries, Integer> {
    // select fields from countries where name='[param]'
    Countries findByName(String name);
}
```

My test

```
package me.givo.nationdbapiproject.repository;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;

@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
public class ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private ICountriesJpaRepository repository;


    @Test
    public void countCountries() {


        System.out.println(repository.count());
        System.out.println(repository.getById(167).getNational_day());
       

        assertEquals(239, repository.findAll().size());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGetAngola() {
        System.out.println("National day: " + repository.findByName("Angola").toString());

        assertEquals("Angola", repository.findByName("Angola").getName(), "Not Angola!");
    }
}
```

This is the debug output (don't know why it's formatted like this, sy) Update: Just paste it again and it gets the right format.

```
20:22:35.018 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [me.givo.nationdbapiproject.repository.ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest]: ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
20:22:35.063 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [me.givo.nationdbapiproject.repository.ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest]
20:22:35.098 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [/home/jose/Java_Projects/nation-db-api-project/target/classes/me/givo/nationdbapiproject/NationDbApiProjectApplication.class]
20:22:35.099 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration me.givo.nationdbapiproject.NationDbApiProjectApplication for test class me.givo.nationdbapiproject.repository.ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest
20:22:35.102 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [me.givo.nationdbapiproject.repository.ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest]: using defaults.
20:22:35.102 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]
20:22:35.115 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@247310d0, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@1033576a, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener@303cf2ba, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@76494737, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@4a003cbe, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@4082ba93, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@17fc391b, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@2b30a42c, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@609e8838, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@359df09a, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@43df23d3, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@6d60fe40, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@792b749c, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@23e84203, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener@19932c16]
20:22:35.117 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@c430e6c testClass = ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@312aa7c testClass = ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class me.givo.nationdbapiproject.NationDbApiProjectApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@536f2a7e key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6f27a732, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@2cdd0d4b, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@482bce4f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@4da4253, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@53cc893, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@66498326, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
20:22:35.128 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener - Performing dependency injection for test context [[DefaultTestContext@c430e6c testClass = ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest, testInstance = me.givo.nationdbapiproject.repository.ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest@6a8658ff, testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@312aa7c testClass = ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class me.givo.nationdbapiproject.NationDbApiProjectApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@536f2a7e key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6f27a732, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@2cdd0d4b, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@482bce4f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@4da4253, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@53cc893, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@66498326, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]].
20:22:35.146 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils - Adding inlined properties to environment: {spring.jmx.enabled=false, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.5)

2021-10-04 20:22:35.392  INFO 3021 --- [           main] m.g.n.r.ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest      : Starting ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest using Java 17-ea on givo1 with PID 3021 (started by jose in /home/jose/Java_Projects/nation-db-api-project)
2021-10-04 20:22:35.395  INFO 3021 --- [           main] m.g.n.r.ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-10-04 20:22:35.681  INFO 3021 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-10-04 20:22:35.724  INFO 3021 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 38 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-10-04 20:22:36.031  INFO 3021 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-10-04 20:22:36.061  INFO 3021 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.5.7.Final
2021-10-04 20:22:36.140  INFO 3021 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-10-04 20:22:36.209  INFO 3021 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-10-04 20:22:38.874  INFO 3021 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-10-04 20:22:38.898  INFO 3021 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
2021-10-04 20:22:39.254  INFO 3021 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-10-04 20:22:39.258  INFO 3021 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-10-04 20:22:39.556  INFO 3021 --- [           main] m.g.n.r.ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest      : Started ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest in 4.409 seconds (JVM running for 4.971)
2021-10-04 20:22:39.976  INFO 3021 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@c430e6c testClass = ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest, testInstance = me.givo.nationdbapiproject.repository.ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest@6a8658ff, testMethod = countCountries@ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@312aa7c testClass = ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class me.givo.nationdbapiproject.NationDbApiProjectApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@536f2a7e key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6f27a732, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@2cdd0d4b, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@482bce4f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@4da4253, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@53cc893, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@66498326, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@8d810f2]; rollback [true]
Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from countries countries0_
239
Hibernate: select countries0_.country_id as country_1_1_0_, countries0_.area as area2_1_0_, countries0_.country_code2 as country_3_1_0_, countries0_.country_code3 as country_4_1_0_, countries0_.name as name5_1_0_, countries0_.national_day as national6_1_0_ from countries countries0_ where countries0_.country_id=?
1821-11-28
Hibernate: select countries0_.country_id as country_1_1_, countries0_.area as area2_1_, countries0_.country_code2 as country_3_1_, countries0_.country_code3 as country_4_1_, countries0_.name as name5_1_, countries0_.national_day as national6_1_ from countries countries0_
2021-10-04 20:22:40.612  WARN 3021 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1009
2021-10-04 20:22:40.613 ERROR 3021 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : DAY_OF_MONTH
2021-10-04 20:22:40.848  INFO 3021 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@c430e6c testClass = ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest, testInstance = me.givo.nationdbapiproject.repository.ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest@6a8658ff, testMethod = countCountries@ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest, testException = org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@312aa7c testClass = ICountriesJpaRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class me.givo.nationdbapiproject.NationDbApiProjectApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@536f2a7e key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6f27a732, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@2cdd0d4b, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@482bce4f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@4da4253, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@53cc893, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@66498326, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]
2021-10-04 20:22:40.864  INFO 3021 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-10-04 20:22:40.865  INFO 3021 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-10-04 20:22:42.440  INFO 3021 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

I try the hibernate query on mysqlworkbench and it select all the countries as spectated:

```
Hibernate: select countries0_.country_id as country_1_1_, countries0_.area as area2_1_, countries0_.country_code2 as country_3_1_, countries0_.country_code3 as country_4_1_, countries0_.name as name5_1_, countries0_.national_day as national6_1_ from countries countries0_;
```

Any help will be really appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent first question. I'm stumped and that exception doesn't seem to be very helpful. I do have a pointer for you but unfortunately it won't fix your problem. The proper case for databases is snake_case as you are using but for Java you should be using pure camelCase instead of the mix you have right now (JPA will take care of the conversion for you) so for example it should be ```private java.sql.Date nationalDay;``` and  ```repository.getById(167).getNationalDay()```

Comment: Thanks I was afraid on get an error cuz using different names than the ones in the DB. I will change them all.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found where was the issue. As I mentioned above I am using the  [MariaDB Tutorial](https://www.mariadbtutorial.com/getting-started/mariadb-sample-database/) database "Nation". Well I initially deployed it on a GCP SQL instance and added the SQL DRIVE to my project instead of the MariaDB one. Now I just changed the DRIVE to the MariaDB one on my project next  I changed the driver class name from my application.properties and finally all work great! Thanks!

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```